# What's wrong with these Apache rewrite?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I've got a set of rewrites that is supposed to catch any requests for `/cache/images/*` that doesn't exist on the file system and return a generic image according to a suffix (a corresponding *_1.jpg for requests for assets like `/cache/images/foo_1.jpg` that don't exist).

The code chunk below works for most cases but is also matching all requests that end in `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` or `3.jpg`, such that "domain.com/1.jpg" is also returning the `/images/generic_1.jpg` generic image.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cache/images/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*1.jpg /images/generic_1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule .*2.jpg /images/generic_2.jpg [L]
RewriteRule .*3.jpg /images/generic_3.jpg [L]
```

If I copy the second `RewriteCond` in front of the 2.jpg and 3.jpg `RewriteRule`s, it works as designed but I'd like to do this properly and have the `RewriteCond` apply to the three `RewriteRule`s below it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that you can't have multiple RewriteRules apply to a single RewriteCond? I know that typically you apply multiple RewriteConds to a single RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1):

`[L]` - means last rule to evaluate: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule (-: Can you take it from here ... ?

**Edit 1** - Cleaning up the Rules:

If your files are named in this pattern, you *could* do something like this:

```
RewriteRule .*(\d{1,}).jpg /images/generic_$1.jpg
```

`\d{1,}` - matches a digit 1 digit or larger; put this in a pair of "`()`" means "save the matched string to `$1`" (aka first match), which you can then use in the destination path.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks. I thought it was the last rule to evaluate only if it matched? Sort of a "thus far but no further" thing to break out of the current RewriteCond if you find a match.

Comment: "thus far but no further" -- sums it up nicely.

Comment: Unfortunately, so far removing the `[L]` flags is not solving the problem.

Comment: See Edit 1 above